# Map Image Overlay App

Tags: applications, google-maps

I want to take a picture of a trail map, then overlay it on google maps or somehow use it as a navigation image linked to GPS? I want to do this all on the phone, while i'm hiking/walking about and encounter a trail map. How can i do this?

Comment: Generally speaking app recommendations are considered off-topic here as outlined in the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq).  If you can edit your question to make it more of a "how do I do this" question rather than a "is there an app that can" question you'll probably be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you [Custom Maps](http://www.custommapsapp.com/) is exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[Locus](http://www.locusmap.eu/) supports that by a built-in function [On Board Map Calibrator](http://docs.locusmap.eu/doku.php?id=manual:functions:on_board_map_calibrator&s[]=board&s[]=calibrator).

You can overlay and calibrate any picture over any map source supported by Locus.

[image: On Board Calibrator]